# Preferred SQLite datatype for cross-platform file paths?

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

In the beginning I used VARCHAR, at least until I found out that it supposedly doesn't support Unicode, for which reason I then switched to NVARCHAR. However, I encountered the need to insert invalid Unicode data into the database (stemming from the fact that on Linux paths are arbitrary bytes and therefore can contain messed up Unicode data).

So now I have to switch the data type again, but I'm stumped on the possibilities. After looking at SQLite docs; the following is "only a small subset of the datatype names that SQLite will accept":

- CHARACTER
- VARCHAR
- VARYING CHARACTER
- NCHAR
- NATIVE CHARACTER
- NVARCHAR
- TEXT
- CLOB

I'm aware of the possibility to store file paths with BLOB, but it doesn't feel right to store data that is text most of the times as BLOB.

**Is there a preferred/idiomatic SQL data type to use for this use-case: text that's Unicode compliant *most of the time*?**

If possible, that data type should transparently convert to and from Python's `str` data type with surrogateescapes (surrogateescapes are Python's way to still be able to represent faulty file paths with `str`).

I couldn't find help for this use-case by googling, so I will appreciate any help or pointers here!

Comment: If you read the documntation carefully then you will see that there is no difference between all these data types. The resulting affinity in any case is `TEXT`.

Comment: Affinity? I'm a noob to SQL, I've started to learn it just a few days ago. But I guess if there's only TEXT, NUMERIC, INTEGER, REAL and BLOB, I will have to use BLOB :/ Why is this so hard

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html is absolutely essential reading for understanding how sqlite works. It explains affinity and many other things.